# Видеокарта Nvidia

Tags: nvidia

У меня видеокарта Nvidia Quadro RTX 3000(for notebooks),следовательно, у меня ноутбук и она встроена в плату, и в последнее время она выводит артефачит (выводит фиолетовые полосы на экран, (это можно увидеть на фотографии)), может быть ли это проблема с какими-то програмными глюками, по типу прошивка BIOS и тд., либо это всё таки физические проблемы по типу с чипом, или же проблеиы с охлаждением.  Посоветуйте что делать!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это на 99% не связанно с ПО. Скорее всего, это явление не связанно с охлаждением. Чаще всего такое поведение проявляется при недостаточно качественных соединениях в коннекторах, шлейфах, проводах, а также шарах припоя чипов. Ну и конечно же необходим визуальный осмотр конденсаторов. Вероятнее всего, вам нужно будет обратиться за ремонтом в мастерскую или сервисный-центр.

Comment: Скорее всего сансара для видюхи. Во всяком случае сама эта проблема не решится и я солидарен с @DiD

Comment: Спасибо за совет, @DiD